# Issue with JACK on Raspian

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, raspbian, jack

After a successful configuration, build and installation of JACK v.2 from source, I am trying to compile a simple JACK client example:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/jack $ gcc -o simple_client simple_client.c -l jack
```

However, the compiler returns the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc7341zz.o: undefined reference to symbol 'sin@@GLIBC_2.4'
//lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libm.so.6: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Are they probably due to the ARM processor architecture? Can you, please, suggest me some hint about how to solve them?

Source code of the `simple_client.c` file is available at [this](https://github.com/jackaudio/jack2/blob/master/example-clients/simple_client.c) link. Furthermore, it has been successfully compiled and tested on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Does adding `-lm` to the _end_ of your gcc command line change something?

Comment: @Ctx, I am able to compile the source file adding the `-lm` option.

Comment: However, why do I need to link the math library too? Theoretically, including `math.h` inside the source file should be enough to do complex calculations, isn't it?